# What are merge request versions in GitLab and is that a specific GitLab feature?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, commit, git-merge

In gitlab if I have an open pull request with some commits on it. On the changes panel I can see this dropdown with a version history.

[image: gitlab MR history]

[image: gitlab commit hashes]

These versions seem to be related to the branch or merge request itself, since I can see versions pop up when I add new commits or when I force push an amended commit (which seems weird since force pushes are supposed to rewrite the branch history)

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push origin branch --f
```

But I cannot find any of the version refs in my local repository, besides the latest one:

```
git log 1d2ee59b
```

gives me the log, but

```
git log 1c7b76e4
git log 09dc0bb8
```

throws `unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

So I'm wondering, is this a feature in GitLab (like some kind of custom reflog related to PRs/Branches, or is it a git feature I don't know about or understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Git feature. Which means that it must be a GitLab feature.

Yes, force pushes do rewrite branches. But let's just consider
git-rebase(1) (local operation): a rebase might make the old commits
unreachable from that branch. Then they are only stored in the reflog. And
eventually the reflog expires and the commits are garbage-collected. But
there is nothing stopping you from hooking into the rewriting machinery
and storing refs to the *old* tips of the branch on every rebase. Maybe
like this:

```
refs/branch-history/<branch-name>/1
refs/branch-history/<branch-name>/2
refs/branch-history/<branch-name>/3
refs/branch-history/<branch-name>/4
```

Where you did your first rebase on “1” and so on. Now the commits from the
old branch are reachable again (via those refs) and thus will never get
garbage collected.

GitHub in fact keeps all ref writes by writing them to an [audit log](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20150624094919.GC5436@peff.net/):

> Yeah, we face this problem at GitHub. We actually write every single ref
> write to $GIT_DIR/audit_log, which is essentially a reflog with the
> refname prepended. The key, though, is that it isn't ever *read* by git
> for reachability. So it becomes an immutable log of what happened, and
> we can happily prune the reflog to drop objects.

And now (since Git 2.42) you can use `gc.recentObjectsHook` in conjunction
with such a file in order to keep all commits from *all* previous versions
alive, effectively implementing what GitLab already does. You do that by
supplying a hook program which prints all the commits that should be kept
alive. (Giving the commit that was at the tip of the branch will keep all commits reachable from that commit alive as well.) And if you have an “audit log” on that format then your program
simply needs to print the file.